# I want to know about wife-beating according to shariah

Tags: sharia, nikah

I live, with my husband and child, in my father-in-law’s house where he is the master of the house. My husband beats me on minor issues, saying that it is recommended in Islam to beat his wife.

My parents-in-law are aware of the matter but they don't reprimand their son, thinking that he is an Islamic man who leads life according to Islamic law.

I want to know what the Shari'ah says about wife-beating.

Comment: beating is restricted to the most extreme situations, there are several other measures that must be tried before one resorts to beating - and even then it is not allowed to harm the person! This is described very clearly in Quran.

Comment: You should report your husband to the police.

Answer (score 2):

A story is narrated about The nabi (SAW) when he would tap his wife on the shoulder with his miswak (small stick about half the length of your hand and the width of your pinky finger).

Now people who try and make a bad person of the Nabi (SAW); Allah guide them; use this as a story to tell.

but can you imagine a miswak inflicting almost any amount of pain on anyone?
I'd like to see someone try!